# How does StackOverflow avoid file extentions and GET parameters in its URLs?

Tags: url, dynamic

It's always boggled me. When you ask a question on stack over flow the url does not have any get statement. It also does not have any extension like .cgi or .php.

However it is not a static html page it is database driven since it changes when you post answers or questions.

Does it have something to do with their .htaccess configuration. How can one achieve a similar effect.

Using php or another language how can someone create a dynamic editable php without manually doing it, for example via a form like the way I submitted this question.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html or http://www.iis.net/download/urlrewrite

Comment: Look into "clean URLs" or "pretty URLs" and "mod_rewrite".

Comment: Take a look at stuff like mod_rewrite (for Apache).

Comment: [file_put_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php), anyone? ;)

Comment: "Search engine friendly URLS" is a good [search term](http://www.google.com/search?q=search+engine+friendly+urls)...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[**Pretty/Clean/Fancy URLs**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rewrite_engine)

Essentially, the web server knows that segments of the URL are actually GET parameters and it "re-writes" the URL before handing it off to PHP/Ruby/.NET/etc.

For example, Apache uses the [`mod_rewrite`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) module to accomplish this behavior.

Answer (score 3):

While **I** can't speak for Stackoverflow, I know that one common way is to use [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html) to convert the pretty url to one with "GET" parameters.  Many solutions wrap mod_rewrite, other ways include [non-apache] web servers.

This [cheetsheet](http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/) is also very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

These are called [Clean URLs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL), otherwise known as pretty or friendly URLs:

> Clean URLs, RESTful URLs or user-friendly URLs are purely structural
>   URLs that do not contain a query string and instead contain only the
>   path of the resource (after the scheme [e.g. http] and the authority
>   [e.g. example.org]). This is often done for aesthetic, usability, or
>   search engine optimization (SEO) purposes. Other reasons for designing
>   a clean URL structure for a website or web service include ensuring
>   that individual resources remain under the same URL for years, which
>   makes the World Wide Web a more stable and useful system, and to make
>   them memorable, logical, easy to type, human-centric, and long-lived.

Each web server has its own method to manage clean URLs.  Apache uses mod_rewrite reading rules from the `.htaccess` file.  There are a lot of examples on Stack Overflow on how people are using this:

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=htaccess+rewrite

With most webservers you manage a set of rules on how to rewrite URLs to get requests that trigger named scripts.  For instance, you might request `/questions/8811192/question-title` but the server rewrites that to `/mywebsite.php?id=8811192&convention=questions` then your script mywebsite.php is run with the parameters id and convention set so your script knows what the user requested originally.  It then consults a database and creates the page dynamically.

Consult your web server documentation for more information on clean URLs.

Answer (score 1):

Mod_rewrite is one example. That can be used I hide .php extensions in your application.

Or if you're using an application platform like any of the java stuff or django or flask for python or ruby on rails or rake for ruby or etc etc etc.

Its about how the web server handles brokering the request to the application layer you're using to handle interactivity. From the mod_php plugin to fast_cgi to wsgi, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Some frameworks just do it that way by default.

Have a look at Yii or Zend Framework for example, they will let you achieve that effect.

They usually enlist the web server to assist with making it happen.

Answer (score 0):

Url path doesn't have to be bounded to any physical location on a filesystem.

You can parse url in your web application and execute code mapped to specific url pattern. Think of it as an internal, in-application mod_rewrite. Most of modern web frameworks have some kind of url-based dispatcher.

However, if you're using cgi scripts or cgi-like execution of application (php-cgi for example, which in fact is a fast-cgi protocol server), you will have to use mentioned mod_rewrite or some similar solution depending on a web server you're using.