# How to get Stack Overflow SEO friendly URL structure in Nuxt.js?

Tags: vue.js, redirect, nuxt.js, seo, friendly-url

Stack Overflow has the following URL structure `stackoverflow.com/questions/{question ID}/{question title}`, and if you misstype the `{question title}` you will be permanently redirected `301` to the correct URL as long as you have the correct `{question ID}`.

Assuming that I have both the `id` and the `slug`, how can I make the same URL structure that Stack Overflow has in `Nuxt.js` with `SSR`?

Edit: Apprently the URL structure is known as [Clean URL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_URL).

I have tried using a fully dynamic URLs with `pages/x/_.vue`, but that gives me a "new" page for each request and does not give a 301 redirect.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8811265/2044241) suggest the following: `/questions/8811192/question-title` could be rewritten to `/mywebsite.php?id=8811192&convention=questions`. So if I can interpret `/qeustions/{id}/{title}` as just `/qeustions/{id}` I could be halfway there I guess.

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far?

Comment: Hi @kissu I have tried using a fully dynamic URLs with `pages/x/_.vue`, but that gives me a "new" page for each request and does not give a 301 redirect.

Comment: Vue is front end framework written in JavaScript that runs on the client.  It is **not possible** for such a framework to issue 301 redirects.   301 redirect **must** be issued by a web server.  You might be able to change the URL using JavaScript, but that may not be the same for SEO.

Comment: Rather than adding details in comments, please [edit] your question to add requested information. You can then comment saying that you have done so. Comments here may get hidden by "show more comments" or could be deleted without notice.  Editing updates into your question ensures that they don't get lost and that everybody who wants to answer the question sees them.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller I am using Nuxt.js which has this capability, in for example `serverMiddleware`.

Comment: `serverMiddleware` runs only once, when you do have your SPA, you're only using client side navigation.

Comment: @kissu I am using SSR, and not SPA. I updated the questions to reflect that.

Comment: Nuxt is an isomorphic framework, meaning that it will run on server then on the client. Meanwhile, it is not a MPA (multi page app) like Wordpress. Once your backend app is served and hydrated on end user's browser, you'll stay in SPA. So, if your app is SSR, it will be SSR then SPA (rather than SPA only for example).

Comment: @kissu so this is not impossible with Nuxt?

Comment: You can probably totally do that with Nuxt. You will just not have a redirect but either just strip the `title` and simply keep the ID I guess.

Comment: @kissu I posted an answer that works for me as far as I can see. Would love some feedback about what you think. Are there negatives in the way I did it, and how can I improve it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Nuxt 2

The following works for me, but I am not sure if it's the exact same as how the Stack Overflow URL structure works.

I am using `async asyncData` to get content from the database, and as you can access
[context](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/internals-glossary/context/) and `redirect`, `req` and `res` as parameters you can perform a `301` redirect.

First I am using [unknown dynamic nested routes](https://nuxtjs.org/docs/features/file-system-routing/#unknown-dynamic-nested-routes) in my folder like this `/pages/folder/_.vue`. Which will catch all routes including `domain.com/folder/{id}` and `domain.com/folder/{id}/{title}`.

To get the ID of in the requested url you can split the pathMatch and get the first element, like this `params.pathMatch.split('/')[0]`.

Then I use the id to get the content from the database, which is Strapi in my case. Like this `await $strapi.findOne('contentType', id)`.

After that we can create the actual URL we want like this `/folder/${data.id}/${data.slug}`. Note: the `data.slug` culd be replaced with the `data.title` which could be converted to a URL friendly string.

Finally we can match the user requested URL with the actual URL of the content `if(route.fullPath !== actualURL)`, and if the requested url is not the same we can performe a redirect with `redirect(301, actualURL)`.

My entire code:

```
async asyncData({ redirect, req, route, app, $strapi, error, params }) {
    try {
        const recipeID = params.pathMatch.split('/')[0];
        const matchingRecipe = await $strapi.findOne('recipes', recipeID);
        const correctPath = `${app.localePath('recipes')}/${matchingRecipe.id}/${matchingRecipe.slug}`;
        if(route.fullPath !== correctPath) {
            console.log(`Redirect: ${route.fullPath} => ${correctPath}`);
            redirect(301, correctPath);
        }
        return {
            recipe: matchingRecipe
        }
    } catch(e) {
        console.log(e)
        error({ statusCode: e.statusCode, message: e.original });
    }
    
},
```

## For Nuxt 3

For Nuxt 3 I have an composable called `useRedirect`, which looks like the following:

```
> composables > useRedirect.ts

import type { AnyRecordResponse, RecordTypes } from '~~/types/strapi';

export default function (response: AnyRecordResponse, recordType: RecordTypes) {
  if (!response || !recordType) {
    showError({ statusCode: 404, statusMessage: 'Page Not Found' });
    return;
  }

  const { path, query } = useRoute();
  const correctPath = useGetURL(response.data, recordType, false);

  // Redirect page if URL is wrong.
  if (correctPath !== path) {
    navigateTo({
      path: correctPath,
      query: { ...query }
    },
    { redirectCode: 301 });
  }
  return correctPath;
}
```

To get `domain.com/folder/{id}/{title}` in Nuxt 3 your folder structure should look like this:

```
> pages > SOMETHING > [id] > [[slug]].vue
```

Double brackets around slugg makes it optional, so you can reach the page with only the id like this `domain.com/folder/{id}`.

The composable `useRedirect` you should call on the page where you want to redirect.